# How to clear the scrollback in the screen command?

Tags: linux, command-line, gnu-screen

I use the `screen` command for command-line multitasking in Linux and I set my scrollback buffer length to a very large value. Is there a key combination to clear the buffer for a certain tab when I don't want it sitting there anymore?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10932487/gnu-screen-how-to-clear-scrollback-and-screen-at-once for how to clear the screen at the same time.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

[This thread](http://osdir.com/ml/gnu.screen.user/2006-01/msg00029.html) has the following suggestion:

> In the window whose scrollback you want to delete, set the scrollback to zero, then
>   return it to its normal value (in your
>   case, 15000).
>
> If you want, you can bind this to a
>   key:
>
> bind / eval "scrollback 0" "scrollback 15000"

You can issue the `scrollback 0` command from the session as well, after typing `C-a :`.
HTH.

Comment: Excellent, I didn't know you could change it on the fly!

Comment: Google aside, the purpose of Stack Overflow is to be the place for canonical answers, so I for one am fine with things being duplicated in a place where I know they can be found.

Comment: That's why I had wuoted the solution as well. And we could argue about google but with those simple keywords it was the very first hit for me. 

And actually I had read that message on the mailing list when it was posted, that's why I had remembered.

Comment: A dumber but easier to remember / type alternative `yes | head -100000`, or just `yes | cat -n`, or `seq 1 999999` and Ctrl-C when you see a number higher than your scrollback length.  Only on a local terminal though, might be too slow on a remote connection.  Assuming you want to purge sensitive info. from the scroll back - if you just want an empty scroll back, the answer's the way to go.

Answer (score 14):

- `C-a C` will clear the screen, including the prompt
- `clear` (command, not key combination) will clear the screen, leaving a prompt

ETA: misread the original question; these will just clear the visible text, but will not clear the buffer!

Comment: None of those clear the scrollback buffer though; and the second one creates a new screen window, leaving the previous one still there (press `C-a a` to get back to it).

Comment: I misread the original question, and made a mistake with the second -- thought I could clear that out before spreading the misinformation, but I underestimated how fast people are here :-)

(FTR, my original comment had `C-a c` as another solution)

Comment: I noticed there's a difference between `C-a c` (Ctrl-C + lowercase c) and `C-a C` (Ctrl-C + uppercase C). The lowercase one creates a new screen window and a new shell, and the second one actually clears the current window.

Answer (score 11):

I added the command "clear" as well to clean the current screen. N.B. You have to press enter to regain you prompt.

```
bind '/' eval "clear" "scrollback 0" "scrollback 15000"
```

Also add it to you ".screenrc" to make it permanent.

N.B. I added single quotes around the slash to be sure it didn't interfere in my ".screenrc". May not be necessary.

Comment: That's not what the OP asked for.  This is not an answer - the bit that is duplicates the other answers.

Answer (score -1):

alias cls='printf "\e[3J\033c"'

Clears the screen and scrollback buffer.

Comment: Does not clear screen’s scrollback.

Comment: It did the trick for me. I wonder if the difference is the terminal emulation capabilities.

Answer (score -2):

Command-K seems to be best solution for Mac.
For more details and explanations, please refer to [this page](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31872/how-do-i-reset-the-scrollback-in-the-terminal-via-a-shell-command).

Comment: This refers to a command in the MacOS X "Terminal" program and has nothing to do with GNU screen.

Answer (score -4):

```
^a : clear
```

worked for me on Ubuntu.

Answer (score -7):

From the man page:

```
C-a C       (clear)       Clear the screen.
```

Comment: simple enough misunderstanding, but do read the questions for details