# GNU screen: how to clear scrollback and screen at once

Tags: gnu-screen

I'm looking for a way to clear both the scrollback and the visible screen at once in GNU screen. At the moment I use two separate bindings:

- C-a, C (which is the default one for clearing the visible text)
- `bind _ eval "scrollback 0" "scrollback 15000"` (which clears the scrollback)

Can someone point me to how I can do both in one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out you can just do:

```
  bind _ eval "clear" "scrollback 0" "scrollback 15000"
```

Note that the order seems to matter: it doesn't seem to work every time if you have the "clear" at the end (it always clears the screen, but not always the scrollback).

Comment: This seems to clear the initial prompt as well. Is there any way to start with a clean screen *with* a prompt?

Comment: @detly `bind _ eval "clear" "scrollback 0" "scrollback 15000" "stuff \03"` will press Ctrl-C for you, which abandons whatever was typed at the previous prompt and gives you a new one.